# Specflow TestProfile file

Tags: cucumber, bdd, specflow

I want to use specflow and specrun to parallelize my test execution. I understand I need a profile file with the Execution element set as following: `<Execution testThreadCount="2" />`.

However, I need a sample profile file to insert the above into. Does anyone know a link for a sample profile file? Perhaps an explanation of the profile settings file and how its used? I understand you can also configure multiple browser version testing with this file also? Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

If you add the SpecRun.SpecFlow nuget package to your project, it adds a "Default.srprofile" that you can use a starting point.

Now there is a detailed documentation at http://www.specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-Runner-Profiles/, that you can look at.
You can also download the nuget package (https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/SpecRun.SpecFlow/1.3.0), open it as zip and in the content folder you will find the template for the Default.srprofile file.

Comment: Not always.  It didn't for me.  Can I just create one myself?  Like the questioner above, it would be very helpful if I could get an example of one somewhere.